# Removing attributes after app initialized

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there any way to clean up the `ng-*` attributes after Angular initialization done and make HTML clean?

```
<div class="element-wp" ng-controller="SampleController as smCtrl"></div>
```

And convert it to:

```
<div class="element-wp"></div>
```

I'm new with Angular and maybe my question is silly, but this attribute make DOM confusing and reduce readability.

Comment: No, no removing the attributes afterwards your angular app won't work. If you are concern about html validation you could use `data-ng-*` directives instead.

Comment: `but this attribute make DOM confusing and reduce readability.` ? How can you be more specific?